# How to set user control field values to empty on page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-refresh

How can usercontrol field values like textbox can be set to null on page refresh. However its possible to set null values once page is submitted that is on submit button click but on refreshing page it retains old values. So how those values can be set to null.

Answer (score 1):

in `OnLoad` method of your userControl add this

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
    myTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    //here clear rest of your textboxes make your textboxes clear
}
```

**Edited:**

1. if you don't want clear this textboxes each postback so why you make such a question?
2. get the code I writen up on this message and put it in your click event `method`

Comment: The way u specified will clear all fields once clicked on submit so will never allow me to submit my data as that will be postback. So there might be some other way for page reload.